How to handle forced inclusion with precompiled header in C++ project with CMake?
I am trying to understand how to generate and include precompiled headers with CMake.
Currently, I am utilizing target_precompile_headers from CMake to generate and include the precompiled header in my source files. This works in my C++ project. On the other hand, this CMake directive leads to forced inclusion of the precompiled header (as described in the CMake documentation

The list of header files is used to generate a header file named cmake_pch.h|xx which is used to generate the precompiled header file (.pch, .gch, .pchi) artifact. The cmake_pch.h|xx header file will be force included (-include for GCC, /FI for MSVC) to all source files, so sources do not need to have #include "pch.h".

In my project, I would prefer to avoid this behavior at the moment. I would like to have to explicitly include #include "pch.h" in my source files that actually make use of the header file. Is there a way to achieve this?
Consider a very simple project structure with main.cpp, pch.cpp, pch.h and CMakeLists.txt:
main.cpp
//#include "pch.h"  //even when the header is not explictly included the code works fine

int main() {
    std::vector<double> my_vector;
    std::cout << "Size of vector is "<< my_vector.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

pch.cpp
#include "pch.h"  

pch.h
// pch.h
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#endif // PCH_H

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(MyExecutable main.cpp pch.cpp)

target_precompile_headers(MyExecutable PRIVATE pch.h)

target_sources(MyExecutable PRIVATE pch.cpp)

With this setting everything works fine even if pch.h is not explicitly included in main.cpp. I have tried both Clang and gcc compilers. Is there a way to avoid the forced inclusion and therefore avoid this behavior? This should be considered as an error since pch.h was not explicitly included.

Split your project into several targets, use PCH only in required targets.

This would not fix the problem though. What if all the modules (potentially) need to use the PCH? My idea was to have a control on the pch inclusion. From my understanding, with your approach you would still have forced inclusion on the specified targets which is what I would like to avoid at the moment.

Your question is unless unclear. If you want explicit #include "pch.h" then don't use target_precompile_headers().

I know target_precompile_headers(), I mentioned on purpose the CMake documentation. My question states clearly that I am trying to understand how to avoid forced inclusion and therefore target_precompile_headers(). The explicit #include "pch.h" does not exclude the use of precompiled headers.

The possible dupe: disable precompiled header for a single file

As it is written in CMake documentation:

The list of header files is used to generate a header file named cmake_pch.h|xx which is used to generate the precompiled header file (.pch, .gch, .pchi) artifact. The cmake_pch.h|xx header file will be force included (-include for GCC, /FI for MSVC) to all source files, so sources do not need to have #include "pch.h".
The list of header files is used to generate a header file named cmake_pch.h|xx which is used to generate the precompiled header file (.pch, .gch, .pchi) artifact. The cmake_pch.h|xx header file will be force included (-include for GCC, /FI for MSVC) to all source files, so sources do not need to have #include "pch.h".

So, the target_precompile_headers macro automatically puts your header into the PCH internal list of the project, so the compiler output for pch.h will be automatically linked to the object code of the target, and included in the resulting executable file. The macro is intended for reusing, and you need to specify compiler flags to have control over force inclusion.

If I understand correctly you are suggesting to enable or disable forced inclusion manually. Do you mean by using the COMPILE_OPTIONS of CMake? Do you have any hint on that?

I mean usage of COMPILE_OPTIONS, or CMAKE_C_FLAGS instead, but it does not seem portable

I see your point. My intention was indeed to come up with a cross-platform solution valid for different compilers. I was expecting it to be more straightforward but I don't see it very easily. It would be interesting to find a solution for this kind of problem.

The point is that the PCHs without autoinclusion may confuse at least IDEs and static analyzers not well compatible with CMake policies.

After some testing, I came up with another approach that does not make use of target_precompile_headers and therefore avoids forced inclusion of precompiled header. My intention is to use precompiled header but having to explicitly include #include "pch.h" in main.cpp to have successful build. It is not a definitive solution but I hope it can help/spark some discussion. Referring again to the simple project.
CMakeLists:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(MyExecutable main.cpp)

set(PCH_HEADER "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/pch.h")
set(PCH_SOURCE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/pch.cpp")

set(PCH_OUTPUT "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/pch.hxx.gch") 


# It handles precompiled header
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${PCH_OUTPUT}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++17 -x c++-header ${PCH_HEADER} -o ${PCH_OUTPUT}
    DEPENDS ${PCH_HEADER} ${PCH_SOURCE}
    COMMENT "Building precompiled header ${PCH_OUTPUT}"
)

add_custom_target(pch ALL DEPENDS ${PCH_OUTPUT})

target_sources(MyExecutable PRIVATE ${PCH_HEADER} ${PCH_SOURCE})

add_dependencies(MyExecutable pch)


main.cpp:
#include "pch.h"  //the header must be explicitly included here to have a successful build (this is exactly the behavior I want)

int main() {
    std::vector<double> my_vector;
    std::cout << "Size of vector is "<< my_vector.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


With this approach main.cpp must explicitly include #include "pch.h" to have a successful build which is what I was trying to achieve.
The test was only done with gcc compiler. Are there better solution to this problem? I haven't been able to figure out more robust solutions
